# A few questions about the notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a few questions.
1. when I send a notice that it replaces the old.
I need to increment a counter notification.

2. how to do that when you click on the notification to open certain fragment?

   private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message,int type) {

   ```
       String title = null;
       int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm;
       long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
       title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
       Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
       notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
       PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> how to do that when you click on the notification to open certain fragment?

You cannot open `Fragment` directly. You need to open `Activity` that then will use that `Fragment`

Comment: Yes I know that. but in many applications Clicking a notification opens another window, which is not at the start of the program

Comment: You can open **any** activity you want, it does not need to be starting one

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number if notification come before user last open n and increase  the counter by this way.

```
notification.number += count(here is number of notification);`
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm doing. but still new notice will replace the old and the counter is not displayed